# Fluent API, one-to-one relationship and cascading deletes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have this class:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public bool IsInactive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public Guid AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Question))]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

And using code-first entity framework everything seems to get set up as I'd expect. I have a one-to-many relationship between `Question` and `Answer` and deleting a `Question` would cause the associated `Answer` to disappear (I think).

Now I want to add this to the `Question` class:

```
public virtual Answer RightAnswer { get; set; }
```

I want to have a one-to-one relationship between `Question` and `Answer` (in addition to the one-to-many relationship from the `Answers` and `Question` properties) and this is where the problems start. The problem happens because of cascading deletes. The way the database now sees it, deleting the question would delete the answers (including `RightAnswer`) which would cause it to try to delete the `Question` again (or maybe it's deleting the `Answer` deletes the `Question` which will then delete the `Answer`, either way). To solve this, I need to tell it to *not* cascade deletes for that one-to-one relationship. And, unfortunately, to do that I have to delve into the fluid API and here I'm not sure of exactly the right way to do it.

I have this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.RightAnswer)
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But I'm really unsure if this should be `WithRequiredDependant` or `WithRequiredPrinciple`. Or if it even matters in this case.

(and yes, I know the other solution would be to just add an `IsRight` bool to `Answer`, but now I want to figure out if I can do it this way instead)

Comment: in one-to-one-relationships, it doesnt really matter what is the principal and what is the dependent. In your approach, logic would suggest that the principal to answer is the question it is the right answer to, so .WithRequiredPrinciple() in your mapping. However, I'm not so sure if this would work in this case, as one-to-one relationships are done via PK=FK, and since your entities have differing PK types, I'm not really sure if EF is able to map without an additional FK column.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, although the circular relationships between relational database tables should be avoided when possible, so I would seriously consider the "other approach".

By EF terms, the *principal* of the relationship is the table being referenced and the *dependent* is the table referencing the principal PK through FK.

For the `RightAnswer` defining relationship, the `Question` will be referencing the `Answer` through FK, hence the `Answer` is the principal and `Question` is the dependent.

So from that standpoint your fluent configuration is correct (the word `Dependent` in `WithRequiredDependent` applies to the *entity being configured*, in your case `Question` - from `Entity<Question>`).

However, with the combination of the other one-to-many relationship it's not. Why? Because of the circular dependency. `Answer` has required `QuestionId` FK, so it cannot be created without firstly creating a `Question`. By making `RightAnswer` required the `Question` cannot be created without firstly creating a `Question`. Which creates unresolvable chicken and egg problem.

Therefore the `RightQuestion` should be *optional*. Which leads to another issue. If we make the `Answer` required, EF by convention will consider it being the principal, which is not we want.

So the only working solution with such model is to make both ends *optional*:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.RightAnswer)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("RightAnswerId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Note that the last two fluent API calls are optional and can be skipped. `Map` is used to specify a different FK column name than the conventional in this case `RightAnswer_AnswerId`. And `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` can be skipped because by convention the cascade delete is turned off for *optional* relationships. But being explicit won't hurt, especially when playing/modifying the models.

Comment: Thanks. I'd come to the realization that it had to be optional exactly because it becomes a chicken and egg problem. The issue with the other solution is that only one answer should be right, and having a `IsRight` field makes it possible for more than one to be right. On the other hand, having the `RightAnswer` property doesn't enforce the requirement that the `RightAnswer` actually belongs to the `Question`! Which is perhaps a bigger problem. I guess some of this stuff will just have to be enforced on my end and not on the database end.

Comment: The other problem that pops up with the optional `RightAnswer` is that when creating a new question (with answers) you have to create all those first, then save it to the database, and only then set the `RightAnswer` property and save again. Otherwise it can't figure out who to save first.

Comment: Indeed. Relational databases cannot enforce the first rule with their standard constraints. And two pass save is the only solution for the second. And not speaking about delete. In order to delete `Question`, you'll need first to update it with setting `RightQuestionId` to `null` and then delete it :)

Answer (score 0):

For `One-to-zero/one Relationship`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasOptional(q => q.RightAnswer)
    .WithRequired(q => q.Question)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

For `One-to-one Relationship`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasRequired(q => q.RightAnswer)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(q => q.Question)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. And adding `q => q.Question` causes EF to create yet another column in `Answers` that isn't needed, which is not desirable.